# Android- How to find user id who login

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I made a simple login activity. I use Sqlite for this.  Everything working well but i cant find who login into activity. I cannot access the user's id. 
Is there any documentation or video for this ?

My Login Button Code :

```
public void girisyap(View view){
    String acc= editTextAcc.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass=editTextPass.getText().toString().trim();
    DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(this);

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(acc))
    {   editTextAcc.setError("Bu Bölüm Boş Bırakılamaz!"); return; }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
    {   editTextPass.setError("Bu Bölüm Boş Bırakılamaz!"); return; }

    if(db.checkUser(acc,pass)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AnaSayfa.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Checkuser Database Code :

```
 public boolean checkUser(String Kayitadi,String Kayitsifre){
    String[] columns ={Table_Id};
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection=Kayit_Name+" =?"+" and "+Kayit_Pass+" =?";
    String[] selectionArgs ={ Kayitadi,Kayitsifre };
    Cursor cursor =db.query(Table_Name,
            columns,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    int cursorCount=cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    if(cursorCount>0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This codes catch is there any user in database. But i need to find who did login. What's his id.

Comment: i suggest you move to firebase as is really easy to do this kind of stuff, but if you are using sqlite you will need to generate a random token for each user and store it in the table, after that you can make a Select request to request each user token (id)

Comment: checking data using Email and password 
if email and password is match then it's login then 
Show the email in activity

Comment: you can reffer here buddy https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db

Comment: if you just want to show to the user his name when they log in, just do a select with the user email, so if the login is success and you are doing the intent to the another activity, just in the other activity pass as an putextra from the intent the user email and show it into an edit text

Comment: No, i'll so much thing to do with user's id. I will add specific files so only they can see their files. For now, i'm using recyclerview. It keeps them infos. But they see everyone's files. For this, i need to know who logged in. I'll check that link and firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment section of this question you have 2 choises, either implement Auth0 to get your users ID after they log in or move to Firebase.

But if you just want to show the users email when they log in you can just pass a putExtra to your intent to the other activity, so when the user is succefull login you can have the email of the user. check this snippet

When the login is success (acc and pass are correct, you are going to another `Activity` where it suposes to say Hello "user_email") so, to do this is very simple, just add a `putExtra` before launching your other `Activity`, with this you can send data from one Activity to another.

```
  if(db.checkUser(acc,pass)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AnaSayfa.class);
intent.putExtra("user_email",here your select_method_or_where_you_get_the_email);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Note: you can use this putExtra to pass your users account

```
intent.putExtra("user_email",acc.toString());
```

if it is already an String do not put `toString();`

now , to get your email from the other activity, just do this

```
  Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {

            String n =(String) b.get("user_email");
}
```

happy coding.

Comment: Thanks i know how to putExtra. But i need this something like facebook account login. There is so much thing to do when they logged in. But thank you. I think firebase just for me.

Comment: please , check this article, it will help you out a lot and its gonna be really easy to manage a database , https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Comment: also, there is a guy called TVACStudio on youtube, check him out, he have tons of firebase Tutorials

Comment: its not that hard, im working with firebase since 2 years, if you have any trouble just post a question in the firebase section of stackoverflow, i will be happy to help